# How could I move part of commited files into another commit or reset the commited status

Tags: git

Let’s say I want to rearrange the committed file `app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.haml` from the commit `4d4d4b2` into the commit `46c6be3`.

How could I do it in easier way?

I can only think of that rollback all the commit and re-commit again.

```
+ bafdafa (HEAD, feature/add-omniauth-support) add gems for omniauth fb
|  Gemfile | 11 ++++++-----
|  1 file changed, 6 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)

+ 46c6be3 add omniauth facebook+ devise integration together
|  app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb |  6 ++++++
|  app/models/user.rb                               | 14 +++++++++++++-
|  6 files changed, 69 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)

+ a7d7600 add haml gem
|  Gemfile      |  4 ++++
|  2 files changed, 13 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)

+ 056aae1 refactor: login form view---------
|  app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.haml     | 28 +++++++++++++++-------------
|  3 files changed, 40 insertions(+), 30 deletions(-)

+ 4d4d4b2 generate devise view then convert to haml
|  app/views/devise/confirmations/new.html.haml                  | 10 ++++++++++
|  app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.haml                     | 19
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be smarter ways with `rebase -i`, but you can do, from the root of the repo:

```
# Create a commit like 4d4d4b2 but without the file we don't want
git checkout 4d4d4b2^
git checkout 4d4d4b2 -- .
git reset -- app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.haml #if instead you want to keep part of your edits of this file, 'git gui' may be useful
git commit -m "generate devise view then convert to haml"

# Re-apply the other commits
git cherry-pick bafdafa^^^
git cherry-pick bafdafa^^
git cherry-pick bafdafa^ # this one is actually 46c6be3

# Before going on, we want to add our file
git checkout 4d4d4b2 -- app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.haml
git log -n 1 --pretty=tformat:%s%n%n%b | git commit -a -F - --amend

#Finally, re-apply the last commit
git cherry-pick bafdafa
```